# eye position mapping with the screen pixel

Tags: matlab, mapping, mouse

I am currently doing a project called eye controlled cursor using MATLAB. 
I have few stages before I extract out the center of the iris (which can be considered as a pupil location). face detetcion - > eye detection -- > iris detection -->And finally i have obtained the center of the iris as show in the figure.

Now, I am trying to map this position (X,Y) to my computer screen pixel (1366 x 768).  In most of the journals I have found, they require a reference point such as lips, nose or eye corner. But I am only able to extract the center of iris by doing certain thresholding. How can i map this position (X,Y) to my computer screen pixel (1366 x 768)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you either have to fix the head to a certain position (which isn't very practical) or you **will** have to adapt to the face position. Depending on your image, you will have to choose points that are always on that image and are easy to detect. If you just have one point (like the nose), you can only adjust for the x/y shift of your head. If you have more points (like the 4 corners of the eye, the nose, maybe the corners of the mouth), you can also extract the 3 rotational values of the head and therefore calculate the direction of sight much better. For a first approach, I guess only the two inner corners of the eye (they are "easy" to detect) will do.

I would also recommend using a calibration sequency. You present the user with a sequence of 4 red points in the corners of the screen and he has to look at them. You can then record the positions of the pupils and interpolate between them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your respond.=)Actually my main objective for this project is for those who are paralyzed and only can communicate through their moving eyeball. First of all i will find the face location and eye location and this will fixed for all the time. Unless the user want to re-calibrate. So basically my head will be fix at certain position. 
Thanks for the suggestion! I will try it and will ask you again if i encounter any related problem. Thanks =D

Comment: Ok, in that case, the *fixed head* assumption may be well worth looking at. Although I would really go for some more points to adapt for the head position. This way you don't have to calibrate every time for the same user.